# How to split a string in sql into multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have a table

| id | name | name_path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Product 1 | null |
| 2 | Product 2 | Product 1 |
| 3 | Product 3 | Product 1|Product 2 |
| 4 | Product 4 | Product 1|Product 2|Product 3 |

How can i create an SQL statement that returns

| producttype | product | productflavor1 | productflavor2 | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | null | null | null | 1 |
| Product 1 | Product 2 | null | null | 2 |
| Product 1 | Product 2 | Product 3 | null | 3 |
| Product 1 | Product 2 | Product 3 | Product 4 | 4 |

Comment: Which DBMS? In SQL Server, there's `STRING_SPLIT`

Comment: i was looking into that but could not get that to work to make the desired outcome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the best way i have come up with:

```
select 
    case 
        when name_path is null then name
        when CHARINDEX ('|', name_path) = 0 then name_path
        else  LEFT(name_path, CHARINDEX ('|', name_path)-1) --CAST( CHARINDEX ('|', name_path) as nvarchar)
        --else LEFT(name_path, CHARINDEX ('|', name_path))
        --else SUBSTRING(name_path, LEN(LEFT(name_path, CHARINDEX ('|', name_path))) + 1, LEN(name_path) - LEN(LEFT(name_path, 
            --  CHARINDEX ('|', name_path))) - LEN(RIGHT(name_path, LEN(name_path) - CHARINDEX ('.', name_path))) - 1)
    end as producttype,
    case
        when LEN(name_path) - LEN(REPLACE(name_path, '|', '')) = 0 then name
        else REPLACE( PARSENAME(REPLACE(replace(name_path,'.','---') , '|' , '.'),LEN(name_path) - LEN(REPLACE(name_path, '|', ''))),'---','.')
    end as product,
    case
        when LEN(name_path) - LEN(REPLACE(name_path, '|', '')) = 1 then name
        else REPLACE( PARSENAME(REPLACE(replace(name_path,'.','---') , '|' , '.'),LEN(name_path) - LEN(REPLACE(name_path, '|', ''))-1),'---','.')
    end as productflavor1,
    case
        when LEN(name_path) - LEN(REPLACE(name_path, '|', '')) = 2 then name
        else REPLACE( PARSENAME(REPLACE(replace(name_path,'.','---') , '|' , '.'),LEN(name_path) - LEN(REPLACE(name_path, '|', ''))-2),'---','.')   end as productflavor2,
    case
        when LEN(name_path) - LEN(REPLACE(name_path, '|', '')) = 3 then name
        else REPLACE( PARSENAME(REPLACE(replace(name_path,'.','---') , '|' , '.'),LEN(name_path) - LEN(REPLACE(name_path, '|', ''))-3),'---','.')
    end as productflavor3,
    case
        when LEN(name_path) - LEN(REPLACE(name_path, '|', '')) = 4 then name
        else REPLACE( PARSENAME(REPLACE(replace(name_path,'.','---') , '|' , '.'),LEN(name_path) - LEN(REPLACE(name_path, '|', ''))-4),'---','.')
    end as productflavor4,
    case
        when LEN(name_path) - LEN(REPLACE(name_path, '|', '')) = 5 then name
        else REPLACE( PARSENAME(REPLACE(replace(name_path,'.','---') , '|' , '.'),LEN(name_path) - LEN(REPLACE(name_path, '|', ''))-5),'---','.')
    end as productflavor5,
    case
        when LEN(name_path) - LEN(REPLACE(name_path, '|', '')) = 6 then name
        else REPLACE( PARSENAME(REPLACE(replace(name_path,'.','---') , '|' , '.'),LEN(name_path) - LEN(REPLACE(name_path, '|', ''))-6),'---','.')
    end as productflavor6,
    case
        when LEN(name_path) - LEN(REPLACE(name_path, '|', '')) = 7 then name
        else REPLACE( PARSENAME(REPLACE(replace(name_path,'.','---') , '|' , '.'),LEN(name_path) - LEN(REPLACE(name_path, '|', ''))-7),'---','.')
    end as productflavor7,
    case
        when LEN(name_path) - LEN(REPLACE(name_path, '|', '')) = 8 then name
        else REPLACE( PARSENAME(REPLACE(replace(name_path,'.','---') , '|' , '.'),LEN(name_path) - LEN(REPLACE(name_path, '|', ''))-8),'---','.')
    end as productflavor8,
    table.*
from table
```